# Cannot add foreign key constraint - MySQL workbench modeling

Tags: mysql, database

Using MySQL workbench forward engineering I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

This is the code:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------    
-- Table `Osiguranje`.`Eksperti`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Osiguranje`.`Eksperti` (
  `Br_procjena` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Zaposeleni_JMBG` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `fk_Eksperti_Zaposeleni1_idx` (`Zaposeleni_JMBG` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Zaposeleni_JMBG_UNIQUE` (`Zaposeleni_JMBG` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Eksperti_Zaposeleni1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Zaposeleni_JMBG` )
    REFERENCES `Osiguranje`.`Zaposeleni` (`JMBG` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

`Zaposeleni_JMBG` is primary key in table `Zaposleni`, type is `VARCHAR(20)` (as it also is in table `Eksperti`).

Comment: The `CONSTRAINT` clause indicates that the name of the referenced column in your `Zaposeleni` table is `JMBG`, whereas your comment indicates that the PK of that table is named `Zaposeleni_JMBG`.  Do you have the column name specified correctly?

Comment: Are both tables InnoDB?

Comment: @eggyal My fault, primary key of Zaposleni is JMBG.
Here is model: http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/51485291/file.html